# Android: Calc duration of event from two strings

Tags: java, android, datetime, timestamp

So I'm having a timestamp like for example this one =1570312800
and also the source gives me the start time and the end-time in string format, so let's say it's basically from 18:00 to 01:00 (6PM to 1AM)
I want to calculate the difference between the 2 strings (5 hours), convert that to milliseconds and add it to the timestamp.
Which gets me in trouble is the converting from STRING to MILLISECONDS.

Which would be the cleanest way?

Sample Code:

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(android.icu.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance(android.icu.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

try
{
    c1.setTime(sdf.parse("20:00"));
    c2.setTime(sdf.parse("1:00"));
}
catch (ParseException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Log.d("TIME DIFFERENCE", String.valueOf(c2.getTimeInMillis()-c1.getTimeInMillis()));
```

Comment: `Long.parseString(String timeStamp)` - should work don't it?

Comment: it gives me a: ava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "22:00" and it's Long.parseLong(String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go about this is by parsing the string to a `SimpleDateFormat` like below:

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));            
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));       

c1.setTime(sdf.parse("20:00"));
System.out.println(c1.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: yeah but, if I'm parsing only the hours like "20:00" or "18:00" it gives me something strange instead of a real millisecond time